# How does typescript enum trans-compilation function create 2 keyvalue pairs at once?

Tags: javascript, object, enums, typescript, key-value

In typescript:

http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

```
enum Role {Employee = 3, Manager =5, Admin = 7}
console.log('Roles:', Role[3])
```

Transcompiles into:

```
var Role;
(function (Role) {
    Role[Role["Employee"] = 3] = "Employee";
    Role[Role["Manager"] = 5] = "Manager";
    Role[Role["Admin"] = 7] = "Admin";
})(Role || (Role = {}));
console.log('Roles:', Role[3]);
```

**I just cannot understand how this function works.**

**1. How is it creating 2 key:value pairs at once check  out here:**
[image]

**2. Why does the scope pass in (Role || (Role = {})?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When evaluating:

```
Role[Role["Employee"] = 3] = "Employee";
```

The inner part:

```
Role["Employee"] = 3
```

Sets `Role.Employee` to `3`, but this assignment also returns the value `3`. So, after the assignment is evaluated, effectively you are left with:

```
Role[3] = "Employee";
```

For details see the assignment operator [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Assignment).

At the end `(Role || (Role = {})`, evaluates to `{}`. This guarantees that `Role`, the object passed to the function, is not `null` for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

> How is it creating 2 key:value pairs at once check out here:

Lets take the line :

```
Role[Role["Employee"] = 3] = "Employee";
```

First we get :

```
Role["Employee"] = 3
```

Then we get

```
Role[3] = "Employee";
```

Where `3` is the result of the expression `Role["Employee"] = 3`

So you can use enum to translate number to string OR string to number

> Why does the scope pass in (Role || (Role = {})?

It allows you to split the enum definition across multiple TypeScript files.

## More

An entire section in the book : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html